# Porque se usa o pretérito mais-que-perfeito composto transitivo indireto em "tinham dado para X"?

Tags: tempo-verbal

Que classe gramatical teria a ocorrência em negrito?
Que tipo de construção é?

> Ao que se afigurava, estavam agora mais ousadas, pois **tinham dado para atacar** seres humanos.

*Tinham dado* é pretérito mais-que-perfeito composto (pretérito imperfeito do indicativo do verbo ter + particípio do verbo principal *dar*).
Será que, por ser transitivo indireto, exige o complemento de preposição seguido de infinitivo (*atacar*)?

É essa a justificação do uso desta estruturação gramatical?

Comment: Olá, bem vindo à comunidade! Não percebo que dúvida tens, podes esclarecer? Talvez não percebas o significado do uso desses tempos verbais, ou o porquê de usar esses em particular (então quais esperavas?), ou se queres uma análise semântica, ou uma análise gramatical... Ajuda-me a entender. :)

Comment: Olá @ANeves, agradeço a saudação. Acho que me orientei mais pela segunda, o porquê de usar esses em particular. Um conhecido me respondeu assim:

> "“dar para fazer algo” é uma expressão da língua portuguesa que significa começar a fazer algo."

Entendo o significado da expressão. Minha dúvida tem mais a ver com a estrutura sintática dela, uma análise gramática talvez seja o que procuro.

Comment: Tentei melhorar; procurei que a pergunta ficasse mais explícita, e menos ambígua e subentendida. Vê no [histórico](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/6585/revisions) as alterações, e se não gostares edita por cima ou usa o link "rollback" no topo da tua versão (1.) para reverter para essa versão da pergunta. :)

Answer (score 1):

Dar para + infinitivo = estar se habituando a fazer alguma coisa, iniciar uma atividade, repetindo-a algumas vezes, **dando a impressão de que vai tornar-se um hábito** (em pt-BR é como entendo a expressão)

- Ela agora **deu pra ficar zangada** por qualquer coisa.
- Ele agora **deu pra beber** todos os dias.
- Os elefantes aqui eram tranquilos mas agora **deram para atacar** seres humanos.

Quanto a "tinham" trata-se de **pretérito imperfeito** do indicativo.

Já "tinham dado" é um tempo composto, no caso "mais que perfeito composto", intransitivo, no meu entender.  Atacar é transitivo direto.

Quanto aos exemplos sugeridos por @ANeves, os significados são outros.

1. Será que vai dar para fazer sopa?  Não se trata de uma expressão idiomática.  Dar, nesse caso, significa "ser suficiente".
2. "Dá para passar no mercado..."  = ter condições (fisicas, de tempo, de vontade) de passar no mercado?
3. "Dá para resolver..." = É possível resolver...

Aliás, o verbo "dar" tem um número de significados muito maior do que eu poderia imaginar. Sem considerar os usos idiomaáticos, o **Aulete dá 34 significados diferentes para o verbo.** E muitos deles aceitam a preposição *para* sem mudar o sentido literal, isto é, sem tornarem-se expressões idiomáticas.

Comment: Obrigado, Centaurus. Entendo o significado da expressão Dar para + infinitivo e me sinto grato com sua explicação. E gostaria de saber se há algum nome para esse tipo de ocorrência. Estava revisitando as locuções verbais e tempos compostos e me deparei com essa frase. Estou tentando entender essa estrutura: tempo composto + preposição + v. no infinitivo. Há um nome específico na gramática para esse tipo de ocorrência?

Comment: Contrapontos para "estar se habituando a fazer alguma coisa": 1. «Não temos batatas... será que vai dar para fazer sopa?» 2. «Precisamos de ovos. Dá para passares pelo supermercado a caminho de casa?» 3. «Dá para resolver esse problema com uma "regra de três simples".» Quer dizer, pode ser esse o significado naquele contexto; mas a construção em si consegue ter um âmbito mais alargado.

Comment: Eu entendo "tinham dado para atacar" menos como "começaram a habituar-se a atacar", mas mais como "tinham fugido ao habitual e feito algo fora do normal/comum/esperado". Mas no fundo ambas têm um significado geral mais-ou-menos semelhante.

Comment: @ANeves   Fiz um acréscimo à resposta.